# Arranging data in Excel

Tags: excel, pivot, product, country, product-quantity

I have data in excel. I need help, to arrange it.
[part of the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMH2J.png)

[image]

I need  to write for each product all of the countries where it is sold, separate the countries with " | ", For Example: if a certain product is sold in SPAIN, UK, FRANCE, BRAZIL and RUSSIA the row of this column will show: SPAIN | UK | FRANCE | BRAZIL | RUSSIA.
It's need to be in the same column....

Comment: Multiple index() with match() will do this with iferror() to suppress any not found. Many examples on here.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one easy way you could do it if you want to see what you're doing.
Fill column C and D, result will be in D. Column B needs to be sorted.

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | **Country** | **Product Code Central** | **Country List** | **Formatted List** |
| 2 | UKRAINE | 194 | =IF(B2=B1;C1&"|"&A2;A2) | =IF(B3<>B2;C2;"") |

Answer (score 1):

If you have a version of Excel that understands both TEXTJOIN and FILTER (the former is the most recent, available in Excel 365) the formula below will return the result you describe.

```
=TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE,(FILTER(A$2:A$11,B$2:B$11=D2,"None")))
```

Here A2:A11 has the country names, B2:B11 the product numbers and D2 any value from B2:B11.